# View logs for a heroku one-off dyno that exited

Tags: heroku

Suppose I started a one-off process using this command:
`heroku run:detached "node do-some-stuff.js" --app my-app`
The output of the command is this:

```
/usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/jsplugin.rb:108: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode 040777
Running `node do-some-stuff.js` detached... up, run.3728
Use `heroku logs -p run.3728 -a my-app` to view the output.
```

I can `heroku logs -p run.3728 -a my-app` while the process is being run, however, when process has exited it outputs nothing. How do i view the logs for process that has finished?

Answer (score 1):

If you using a logging plugin, just search for `run.3728`.  For a short period of time, the logs will also still be in the heroku logs if you do `heroku logs | grep run.3728`